# Failed Flutter Install MacOS Catalina With Terminal Message -bash: flutter: command not found"

Tags: macos, flutter, command-line, terminal

[image: my terminal screenshot is attached]I am a new programmer installing flutter on my macbook pro. I downloaded the flutter sdk and located/copied flutter bin location;
/Users/essiet/documents/sayy/flutter/bin

into the .bash PATH. After creating path I keep getting this message "-bash: flutter: command not found"

Comment: Do you use MacOs Catalina and did you update the path variable in your .bash_profile file?

Comment: Same issue :( arriving

Comment: Which Terminal shell you are using bash or zsh?.
May i see you terminal shell screen shot?

Comment: Thomas- Yes, I am using Catalina and yes I have updated the path variable via command nano .bash_profile

Comment: Shruti- I have added the screenshot above

Comment: Thomas- I have updated flutter path to Desktop without any success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MacOS Catalina so, Catalina's terminal uses zsh shell by default.
so you need to change into bash shell.

**Command:**

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

Set your flutter sdk path

Steps:

1.)open terminal

2.) type command:`vim .bash_profile`

3.)to inserting sdk path, press on keyboard 'i'

4.) Paste this line export PATH=[your_flutter_sdk_path]/flutter/bin:$PATH

5.)then press on keyboard `esc` & then press `:` `w` and `q` then press enter.

6.)then Terminate your terminal proper.

7.) reopen your terminal and type `flutter doctor`

I had followed this [youtube_tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xy-qHlaHr6c) for setting path of flutter sdk in MacOs.

Comment: Thanks this has worked. I have been able to run flutter and flutter doctor. Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad to know it, my answer worked for you  to support my answer, please vote it

Comment: Sure thing. Just did.

Comment: @ShrutiRamnandanSharma grt :)

Comment: @AR Thank you so much 